# Cheapest possible TV or monitor to use with retro PCs (PAL)

Tags: monitors, television

I would like to recuperate my youth and play around with Zx81, BBC Micro, Commodore Amiga, etc. All of these use a TV as their display, and in Europe take PAL input.

Can anyone recommend something very, very cheap to use as a monitor?

It doesn't have to be a TV, a CCTV monitor might work I guess. Just so long as it displays a PAL input.

Given the PCs, image quality is not an important factor.